# How to get only one result per inner joined table

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the following database structure:

Place table
[image: Place tabe]

Place_has_Event table

[image: Place_has_Event table]

Event table

[image]

How can I get the closest(soonest) event for each place. So I need first event for all places. I want to get this in a single query.

Comment: Can you please share with us the SQL query that you have written

Comment: place table column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `select min(start)` to get the lowest date (this assumes that events in the past are pruned, or else you can use a `where` clause to filter past events), and `group by location`

This will return the event with the lowest date for each location.

Some syntax may be off, as my experience is with sql-server rather than mysql.

```
Select Event.name, min(Event.start) 
From Event Inner Join Place_has_Event On event.ID = Place_has_Event.Event_ID
Where Event.start > getdate() 
Group By Place_has_Event.Place_ID
```

Add select entries as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it?

```
SELECT t1.* from tbl_name AS t1 
where t1.startdate=(
  select max(t2.startdate) from tbl_name as t2
)
```

Comment: This is not working. It returns just one record (with max date) and not the events with max date for each place.